# Promt message for error fields

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code and its giving error.
I want to prompt error msg for the cells which are having errors.

```
Public Sub OnErrorDemo()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, iLength As Integer
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ErrorHandler:
    For h = 1 To Range("A60").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A&h")
        Select Case IsEmpty(rng)
        Case True
            MsgBox rng.Address & " is empty"
        Case Else
            Select Case IsNumeric(rng)
            Case True
                MsgBox rng.Address & " has a numeric value"
                Select Case rng.HasFormula
                Case True
                    MsgBox rng.Address & " also has a formula"
                End Select
            Case Else
                iLength = Len(rng)
                MsgBox rng.Address & " has a Text length of " & iLength
            End Select
        End Select
    Next h
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim rng As String
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
ErrorHandler:
Set rng = ExcelApplication.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn
For i = 1 To A
For j = 1 To A
Select Case IsEmpty(rng)
      Case True
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 3) = "Row " & i & " Column " & k
End Select

  End Sub 'I have changed the code but its giving object is required

Answer (score 1):

Check this line of your code, I think this might be causing error:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A&h")
```

Instead use this:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & h)
```

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler   ' Enable error-handling routine.
    Dim LastCol As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim rng As Range, iLength As Integer
  LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ErrorHandler:
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & h)
Select Case IsEmpty(rng)
      Case True
        iLength = Len(rng)
        If iLength > 10 Then
            MsgBox rng.Address & "has exceeded the limit. the lenth shold be less than 10"
        End If End Select
  End Sub I've editd code but its gvg appn defined error

Comment: for the first line itself

Comment: Please specify the line.